# No rule to make target *, needed by *

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I can't get what's wrong with my makefile:

```
DIST_PATH = ../dist/libs
BUILD_PATH = ../build

MKDIR_P = mkdir -p

.PHONY: all

SHELL   = /bin/sh
CC      = gcc
FLAGS   = -std=gnu99
CFLAGS  = -fPIC -pedantic -Wall -Werror
LDFLAGS = -shared

LOG_SRCS = $(shell echo log/*.c)
LOG_HEADERS = $(shell echo log/*.h)
LOG_OBJS = $(addprefix $(BUILD_PATH)/, $(notdir $(LOG_SRCS:.c=.o)))
LOG_TARGET = $(DIST_PATH)/liblog.so

all: dirs $(LOG_TARGET)

dirs : 
    $(MKDIR_P) $(DIST_PATH)
    $(MKDIR_P) $(BUILD_PATH)

$(LOG_TARGET) : $(LOG_OBJS)
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)
```

I need to build a shared library from sources in `log/` folder to `../dist/libs` and put obj file in `../build` but I am getting the error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target '../build/log.o', needed by '../dist/libs/liblog.so'.  Stop.
```

**P.S.** I know there are many similar questions but I couldn't get from these questions how to resolve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the source and object files are supposed to be placed in different directories, and there's no implicit rule for that.

You need to add a rule for how to translate a source file to an object file:

```
$(BUILD_PATH)/%.o: log/%.c
```

Now `make` knows how to create the object files from the source files.

---

There's another problem though:

```
$(LOG_TARGET) : $(LOG_OBJS)
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)
```

The command doesn't list any input files, you need to add all the object files to be linked:

```
$(LOG_TARGET) : $(LOG_OBJS)
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)
#                                  ^^
# List of all "prerequisites" (object files) to be linked
```